# How to catch VBScript runtime error "Object required: 'Session'" on cmd line where Session isn't defined for MSI

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, custom-action

Writing a script for a custom `.msi` installer action.  When my script is invoked by an installer, you can get installer properties via `Session.Property("PropName")`

If you don't invoke via installer you get a runtime exception.  I want my script so that I can develop and debug without the installer. How do I catch this error?

I want to do something like:

```
if Session != null 
  setting=Session.Property("prop1")
else 
  setting="SomeOtherSetting"
end if
```

Comment: I believe there's no way of debugging a vbs custom action using the exact same script. I always keep a dummy project that compiles fast just for debugging purposes. BTW, are you trying to access the property during the UI execute?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the VBScript syntax to check for null?

How about this:

```
If (IsNull(Session)) Then
  setting=Session.Property("prop1")
Else 
  setting="SomeOtherSetting"
End If
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ I want to just avoid getting a runtime error. The Session object is automatically initialized somehow during by the installer which invokes my script.  I want to guard against this runtime object by initializing variables i need some other way while i'm debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Session` object isn't defined outside of MSI scripts, so any reference to its properties or methods will raise an exception. To check if an object or a variable is defined, you can use the `IsEmpty` function:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Session) Then
  setting = Session.Property("prop1")
Else
  setting = "SomeOtherSetting"
End If
```

Another possible solution is using the `On Error Resume Next` statement to catch exceptions caused by referencing the properties and methods of the `Session` object:

```
On Error Resume Next

setting = Session.Property("prop1")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  setting = "SomeOtherSetting"
End If
```